# Switching between view controllers without using navigation controller stack

Tags: xcode, uiviewcontroller

i am creating my first app.i have multiple view controller stack in my app. i want to switch view controllers, so i am using this method:

```
        wallViewController *dvc = [[wallViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"wallViewController" bundle:nil];

        dvc.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

        [self presentModalViewController:dvc animated:YES];

        [dvc release];
```

its working fine. but its reloading view controller,like its calling viewdidload each time,but i want to show the previous state of parent view controller as in navigation controller.Please help me.

Comment: allocate the wallViewController in global scope and reference it from there

Comment: why don't you try `UITabbarController`, if you want to keep your `ViewController` state.

Comment: because i also dont want to display tabs. i want to switch manually.

Comment: you're allocating a view controller each time you go through that code... Allocate it once, and present it only. Without more info on what you're trying to do that's all there is.

Comment: i have a main controller, on some button clicks i want to present another view controllers and always want to show the previous state of main controller when i return to main controller from any where.